# How to edit core files in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I want to edit the tree-view package in Atom. I want to add a new item to the context menu. But i can't file where are the files. I can open the config folder and I can see all the community packages I have installed, but where do I find the core files of the editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are packed inside the `app.asar` file. This file is located at the following location in the OS X version.

```
Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar
```

This file is generated by [this build script](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/2893772d1a5df8b6ea394e14ebb8eab637cb731b/build/tasks/generate-asar-task.coffee).

Of course, this package is open-source, so you can view [the code for tree-view on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/tree-view).

GitHub also has [some documentation for developing on official Atom packages](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/8b40c3aaeba4c98730b8d5451b6aba1f09b55911/docs/contributing-to-packages.md).

> The first step is creating your own clone.
>
> For example, if you want to make changes to the `tree-view` package,
>   fork the repo on your github account, then clone it:
>
> ```
> > git clone git@github.com:your-username/tree-view.git
> ```
>
> Next install all the dependencies:
>
> ```
> > cd tree-view
> > apm install
> Installing modules ✓
> ```
>
> Now you can link it to development mode so when you run an Atom window
>   with `atom --dev`, you will use your fork instead of the built in
>   package:
>
> ```
> > apm link -d
> ```

Also, if all you want to do is add another menu item, I wouldn't be surprised if there is an API for doing so from another plugin.

Comment: Can i merge the change I'll do into my built atom, or can I create a new atom executable from my clone? I'd like to always use my fork in this case.

Comment: @PietroCoelho I'm not sure. You might have to build your own fork of Atom. Of just install your own fork of the tree-view plugin and use it instead of the Atom one.