# How to open a file with a single click in atom1.7+ (no pending panes)

Tags: atom-editor

After having upgraded atom from 1.5 to 1.7 I discover a new "feature" that is not practical: all files that are single-clicked are now open in a "pending pane", what means that if nothing is changed in the file, it will be replaced by the next opened file.

It's possible to disable the "pending panes" feature in the settings of atom.

But I also would like to restore the previous behaviour (a single click on the file in the tree view will open the file).

The "tree-view" package settings allow to edit keybindings, but I haven't found anything about mouse clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up Settings from `File` -> `Settings` or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Comma</kbd> there is a setting right at the top of "Core Settings" to `Allow Pending Panes`, uncheck this to disable the Pending Pane functionality:

[image: Screenshot of Core Settings]

Unfortunately restoring the 'single-click' functionality to the TreeView isn't a configurable option as yet.  However there is [pull request #804](https://github.com/atom/tree-view/pull/804) that addresses this problem.

### Advanced: how to try out the updated TreeView now

If you feel brave and want to try out the [updated version of TreeView](https://github.com/Alhadis/tree-view) before it is merged you can actually download it and add it to Atom, albeit not from Package Manager.:

> **Question:** [How to edit core files in Atom Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444401/how-to-edit-core-files-in-atom-editor/31444675).

It is required to clone the appropriate branch of the repository:

`git clone -b single-click-select git@github.com:Alhadis/tree-view.git`

Thanks to Arcesilas for spotting this answer.

Comment: I did mention "It's possible to disable the "pending panes" feature in the settings of atom." in my question but your precision might be useful to other users too. As for the 'single-click' functionality, well I hope this will be merged soon! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I should have been clearer that you had mentioned the setting already.  It's not a great answer so I have updated it with instructions on getting the pre-release version of TreeView running, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hi. I've tryed to install the new version of tree-view but : 1/ There is no need to use apm link when cloning in ~/.atom/packages (since apm link create a link in this very directory when the package is cloned somewhere else, while developping for instance). 2/ There is an error "Could not find module event-kit" at atom startup: I think it could be linked to the fact that this package is not really a package but a fork of a core feature, which is not designed to be used as a package (I may be wrong, I'm just guessing)

Comment: @Arcesilas the majority of core features as you refer to them are actually packages, it's just that they are shipped with Atom out of the box, however they can be overridden by linking them with `apm link`.  I have missed a step, namely you may have to get `npm` to install the package dependencies with `npm install`.

Comment: As I said apm link is not required: when running it, I get a message saying that the file exists: it actually tries to create a link where the package has been cloned. Error message: `Linking /home/olivier/.atom/packages/tree-view to /home/olivier/.atom/packages/tree-view failed: EEXIST, file already exists '/home/olivier/.atom/packages/tree-view'`. Running npm install does not work since there is no package.json

Comment: My instructions do say *not* to check it out in `~/.atom/packages`, Atom is very sensitive to package directories matching the `packageName` in `package.json` in the case of `tree-view` it doesn't matter as the repository is also called `tree-view` - however the above process will work for any package regardless of the repository name.  The `package.json' is [part of the repository](https://github.com/Alhadis/tree-view/blob/master/package.json).

Comment: Ok, I misread the location where to clone the package.
I found some clear information on how to deal with it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444401/how-to-edit-core-files-in-atom-editor/31444675#31444675
It is required to `cd tree-view` before running `apm install` (which may be obvious for some people, but not for those who are not familiar with packages source code and packages workflow) and `apm link -d`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109261/discussion-between-arcesilas-and-richard-slater).